# Sampling from Kolmogorov forward equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, sampling, simulation

I've asked this question over in cross-validated over here:https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/610492/383970
But no answers. I was curious if somebody in this stack has an answer.

I've been learning Gillespie's algorithm to simulate continuous time Markov chains. I understand how the algorithm is derived from the reaction probability density function

$P(\tau, \mu)$ = probability at time $t$ that the event $\mu$ will occur in the time interval  $(t + \tau, t + \tau + d\tau)$

What I don't get is how this guarantees us that we're sampling from the "master equation" or the Kolmogorov forward equations. Why is that sampling with this probability gives us trajectories that follow the distribution given by solving the forward equations?

Comment: The question has an interesting feeling, but lacks many details. Provide the details and a precise statement of your problem, or the question will be most likely ignored or closed.